# How do I get the function of the curve in an image?

Tags: matlab, function, curve

I need get function of the curve, because i need to calculate to get lenght curve.
Firstly I try to get the function from curve

```
[rows, columns, numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);
if numberOfColorBands > 1
   grayImage = grayImage(:, :, 2); % Take green channel.
end
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(grayImage, []);
title('Original Grayscale Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf, 'Name', 'Demo by ImageAnalyst', 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
binaryImage = grayImage < 100;
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(binaryImage, []);
title('Binary Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
axis on;
[rows, columns] = find(binaryImage);
coefficients = polyfit(columns, rows, 3); 
fittedX = linspace(min(columns), max(columns), 500);
fittedY = polyval(coefficients, fittedX);
subplot(2,2,3:4);

plot(fittedX, fittedY, 'b-', 'linewidth', 4);
grid on;
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', fontSize);
ylabel('Y', 'FontSize', fontSize);
hold on;
plot(columns, rows, 'r+', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 10);
```

the test image is next curve

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formula for arc length (s) is

```
  s = Integral Sqrt[1 + (dy/dx)^2] dx,
```

where the limits of the integral at the two x end points. This isn't very tractable for most curves, so you have to resort to adding up small linear pieces.

Comment: I try with the code, but i have a error when i try to integer my function...                                                      formula = poly2sym([coefficients(1),coefficients(2),coefficients(3)]);
formulaD = vpa(formula)
df=@(x)diff(formula(x));
df = df^2 f= @(x)sqrt(1+(df)^2); i = integral(f,0,Inf); and i get this error Error using sym>tomupad (line 1135)
Conversion to 'sym' from 'function_handle' is not possible.
Error in sym (line 151)
                S.s = tomupad(x);
Error in sym/int (line 63)
f = sym(f);

Comment: i only use int instead integral